# Top offset returns incorrectly in Firefox and Opera with image map

Tags: javascript, dom, offset, imagemap

The top offset value returned in Firefox and Opera is different from Chrome, Safari and IE. In the jsfiddle example below, Chrome, Safari and IE return 0, while Firefox returns 543 and Opera returns 523.

Is this a bug with those browsers, or is there some way around this?

http://jsfiddle.net/wHgUW/1/

```
<img src="http://www.archetype-inc.com/guido/tron-poster.jpg" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="50,50,50,50" href="#" />
</map>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox and Opera, the map-element is not actually above the image, but invisible under it.

You can fix your problem by reading the offet from the img-element instead.